# Tuple Output with string.Concat

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I have this dictionary:

```
Dictionary<char, Tuple<char, char>> EngtoJap = new Dictionary<char, Tuple<char, char>>()
{
//My dictionary
}
```

and I'm trying to get the output with this:

```
string output = string.Concat(array.Select(c => EngtoJap.ContainsKey(c) ? EngtoJap[c] : c));
```

I know there is something wrong at the end of the output but I don't know what is it I need to fix for it to get the Tuple.

Thanks and sorry if I'm not clear.

**EDIT:**
Sorry I'll be more specific. My aim is to have an english sentence and change each character to an assigned japanese character in the dictionary.

The result I want is to get random either Item1 or Item2 to replace the english characters in the sentence, then replace each of the changed character in nth position of a japanese paragraph.

After that I want to get the nth position of characters using numericupdown and change them back to english characters to form the sentence. I have another dictionary for this already.

I hope it's not too confusing...

Comment: Could you define what is the result you want to see?

Comment: Are you trying to match words or characters between Japanese and English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
string output = string.Concat(array.Select(c => EngtoJap.ContainsKey(c) ? EngtoJap[c].Item1.ToString() + EngtoJap[c].Item2.ToString() : c.ToString()));
```

You already have the tuple with the `EngtoJap[c]`, so you can use `EngtoJap[c].Item1` to get the first char and `EngtoJap[c].Item2` to get the second char.  If you `ToString()` everything then you can concatenate the two chars and the `Select` knows that you are returning a collection of strings, and those will be concatenated by the `Concat`.

**EDIT** In your edit you say that you are trying to get either Item1 or Item2 randomly.  Would this work?

```
System.Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
string output = string.Concat(array.Select(c => EngtoJap.ContainsKey(c) ? ( random.Next(2) == 1 ? EngtoJap[c].Item1 : EngtoJap[c].Item2 ) : c));
```

Comment: More nice to use `EngtoJap.TryGetValue(c, out v)` rather than first searching with `EngToJap.ContainsKey(c)` and then immediately searching again with `EngtoJap[c]`.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Now just to put it into the main text using numericupdown. really thank you very much